# Export dataset from R to REDCap?

Tags: r, redcap

I want to export a dataset containing personal IDs and other variables to REDCap. Does anyone know how to do it?

I have found a package called REDCapR but it just contains importing from R.

Comment: Do you want to import them to redcap from R or export them from redcap into R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`REDCapR::redcap_write()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_write.html) moves info from a data.frame on your local R instance to the remote REDCap Server.

```r
# Read the dataset for the first time.
result_read1  <- REDCapR::redcap_read_oneshot(redcap_uri=uri, token=token)
ds1           <- result_read1$data
ds1$telephone

# Manipulate a field in the dataset in a VALID way
ds1$telephone <- paste0("(405) 321-000", seq_len(nrow(ds1)))

ds1           <- ds1[1:3, ]
ds1$age       <- NULL; ds1$bmi <- NULL # Drop the calculated fields before writing.

# Upload the data to the server.
result_write  <- REDCapR::redcap_write(ds1, redcap_uri=uri, token=token)
```

Documentation and references:

- The function's page in the reference manual: https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_write.html
- Troubleshooting document: https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/articles/TroubleshootingApiCalls.html#writing
- Other vignettes that describe global approaches to working with R & REDCap: https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/articles/index.html

(I'm the primary REDCapR developer.  The [`REDCapR::redcap_write()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_write.html) function was one of first functions added in [2013](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/commit/bf65ab88f63ef96ba9f198489b3b0ef214474ead).)